# Applescript and Cocoa window positions

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, macos, applescript

I know that using Applescript I can change the size and position of any application's window, but is it possible to get a notification whenever a window has changed it size or position?

If thats not possible, then what I was thinking was making a thread in the background, and constantly check the positions of windows and see if they have changed, if they did then they moved.

But that would take a lot of cpu resources to constantly compare the positions/sizes of window. So is it possible? If not , is there a better way?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but i think there isn't a notification for that. 
I would listen for mouse events. When the mouse was dragged you can check the windoews for changes. Hope that helpa.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but will I be notified when a mouse is dragged or clicked outside of my application?

Comment: Nvm, I figured it out. For those wondering: addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:
Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, it should say: "addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:" 
       found in NSEvents class